# How do I call a button once without going into an infinite loop (Angular)?

Tags: html, angular

Maybe the title is not very clear but here is what I have.

I have a scenario where I have a button in HTML, I call the service when the button is clicked and I want HTML B to know when the button from HTML A is clicked.

A.html

```
<button (click)="passData(a,b,c)">
```

B.html

```
<div *ngIf="fromA()" > 
 {{ showResult() }}
</div>
```

A.component.ts

```
passData(a: string, b:string, c:string) {
  this.Xservice.getData.subscribe(data => res = data);
}
```

B.compoent.ts

```
fromA() {
  this.xService.subscribe( data => res = data ); // This is observable
  if (res !== undefined ) {
    console.log("true returned");
    return true;
  }
}
```

So from this above I have checked the console and it is flooded with logs "true returned" and I was wondering how do I just to call this once when button from A.html is pressed?

Comment: Please create a stackblitz if possible. Is there a relationship between A and B?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `*ngIf`. You can just have

```
fromA():string {
  if // Whatever logic you do
  return "block";
  else return "none";
}
```

Now I'm assuming what you mean is you want HTML B to only show when fromA() is clicked. So you can do this:

```
<div [display] = "fromA()">
 {{ showResults()  }}
</div>
```

Basically, you just set the property `display` to whatever result `fromA()` has. If the button is not clicked (returning `none`), then the HTML is not displayed (`display=none`). If it is clicked (returning `inline`), then the HTML is displayed (`display=inline`).

Of course, you could use any other display properties besides inline to show the HTML.

Comment: so from the first snippet I am assuming that's B.component.ts but if you put that there. How does it know it is from A.compoent? both component and html are independent of each other the only way to communicate is through service.